# How to show $\bar{u}(x)=\liminf_{(\epsilon,x')\to(0,x)}u_{\epsilon}(x')$ is lower semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

I have following questions:

given $\epsilon \in (0,1]$ and $x\in \mathcal{O}$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is an open subset of $R^d$, the map $(\epsilon,x)\to u_{\epsilon}(x)$ is locally bounded, if I know $u_{\epsilon}(x)$ is lower semi-continuous in $x$, how to show that 
$$\bar{u}(x) = \liminf_{(\epsilon,x')\to(0,x)}u_{\epsilon}(x')$$
is also lower semi-continuous...

Also, if let $\varphi\in C^2(\mathcal{O})$ and $\bar{x}$ be a strict minimizer of $\bar{u}-\varphi$, then why there would be a sequence $(\epsilon_n,x_n)\in(0,1]\times\mathcal{O}$ such that
$$(\epsilon_n,x_n)\to (0,\bar{x})$$ 
and
$$u_{\epsilon_n}(x_n)\to\bar{u}(\bar{x})$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you take $u_\epsilon(x) = \chi_{(0,1]}(x)$, then $\bar u (x) = \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$ which is not lower semi-continuous. ($u_\epsilon$ is lower semi-continuous and bounded)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have some question regarding the example. If the space of $x$ is $(0,1]$ then it is not an open subset of $R$... and if the space of $x$ is $R$, the function $\chi_{(0,1]}(x)$ is not lower semi-continuous at $x=1$...I think the $u_{\epsilon}(x)$ is not lower semi-continuous but $\chi_{(0,1)}(x)$ is lower semi-continuous...

Comment: Maybe I have mixed up upper and lower semi-continuous. $u$ is lower semi-continuous at $x$ iff for any sequence $x_n \to x$ so that $x_n≤x \forall n$ you have $u(x_n)\to u(x)$. In this case take $u$ as above with domain all of $\mathbb R$. Then you can check that the condition is satisfied (ie if $x_n ≤ 0$, then $u(x_n)=0$ and any lower limit to $0$ is constant $=0=u(0)$). The function $\bar u$ is not lower semi continuous, since if $x_n \to 1$ from below, eventually $\bar u(x_n)=1$, but $\bar u(1)=0$.